# how to add calculated % into each col and rename col as well

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that looks like this:

[image]

Sample data can be build using:

```
df<- structure(list(Grade = c("Grade 1", "Grade 2", "Grade 3", "Grade 4", 
"Grade 5", "Total"), n_each.x = c(76, 48, 20, 4, 2, 150), n_each.y = c(16, 
17, 8, 2, 0, 43)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
```

now I want to add(%) for col 2 and 3, by using `.x/.x[6]` also rename col 2, and 3. what should I do in order to get a table that will looks like this: For percentage , I would like keep 2 digits if it is not 0. so 1.236 will be 1.24, but 1.00 will be 1. Is it doable?

[image]

for rename part, I know I can do like this:

```
names(df)[2] <- "Test 1"
names(df)[3] <- "Test 2"
```

Is it a way to make it even simpler, something like `df<-df %>% names...`? if it is doable, I would like to have a code start with df<-df then complete both task in one chunk. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) dplyr** Use setNames and mutate/across as follows:

```
library(dplyr)

fmt <- function(x) 
   sub("\\.0+%", "%", sprintf("%d (%.2f%%)", x, 100 * x / tail(x, 1)))

df %>% 
 setNames(c(names(.)[1], paste("Test", seq_len(ncol(.)-1)))) %>%
 mutate(across(-1, fmt))
```

If you know you only have the 2 Test columns the setNames line could be written as:

```
 rename("Test 1" = n_each.x, "Test 2" = n_each.y) %>%
```

The result is:

```
    Grade      Test 1      Test 2
1 Grade 1 76 (50.67%) 16 (37.21%)
2 Grade 2    48 (32%) 17 (39.53%)
3 Grade 3 20 (13.33%)  8 (18.60%)
4 Grade 4   4 (2.67%)   2 (4.65%)
5 Grade 5   2 (1.33%)      0 (0%)
6   Total  150 (100%)   43 (100%)
```

**2) Base R** A base R approach is similar (fmt is from above):

```
nc <- ncol(df)
replace(df, -1, setNames(lapply(df[-1], fmt), paste("Test", seq_len(nc-1))))
```

or if we knew we had only two tests then we could write the following instead:

```
data.frame(df[1], "Test 1" = fmt(df[[2]]), "Test 2" = df[[3]], check.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: For percentage , I would like keep 2 digits if it is not 0. so 1.236 will be 1.24, but 1.00 will be 1. Is it doable?

Comment: Have changed it.

Answer (score 2):

`Janitor` seems to be fit for this job

```
library( janitor )
library( tidyverse )
df %>% 
  filter( !Grade == "Total") %>% #remove totals, they mess up the percentages
  adorn_totals( where = "row" ) %>% #add totals without messing with percentages
  adorn_percentages("col") %>%
  adorn_pct_formatting( digits = 2 ) %>%
  adorn_ns( position = "front" ) 

#   Grade      n_each.x     n_each.y
# Grade 1  76  (50.67%) 16  (37.21%)
# Grade 2  48  (32.00%) 17  (39.53%)
# Grade 3  20  (13.33%)  8  (18.60%)
# Grade 4   4   (2.67%)  2   (4.65%)
# Grade 5   2   (1.33%)  0   (0.00%)
#   Total 150 (100.00%) 43 (100.00%)
```

Comment: Was about to post similar answer.  Upvoted.